# How to resolve 'this' keyword within nested object literals

Tags: javascript

I am trying organize object literal code as such. Is there a clean/efficient way to point 'this' in the inner function which points to 'category' to 'obj'?

```
var obj = {
    outerFunc : function () {
        console.log(this);
    },
    outer_prop : 1,
    category : {
        innerFunc : function () {
            console.log(this);
        },
        inner_prop : 2
    }
};

var my_obj = Object.create(obj);
my_obj.outerFunc();
my_obj.category.innerFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke your `innerFunc` with the `call()` method, to which you can pass what you want `this` to be:

```
my_obj.category.innerFunc.call(obj);
```